# windows wont start via grub

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, boot, grub

So i recently installed ubuntu ( i had windows 10 already installed on my SSD). I installed it on a partition on my HDD. I tried to make it so if I boot from the HDD grub would start. When grub generated the config file it recognized the windows and added it to the list. If i try to boot windows with grub, the system just reboots. If i try to boot the pc via Windows Boot manager(SSD), windows boots fine. I tried booting from all partitions of the SSD with grub but none seems to work. [Grub Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0J4D.png), [output of fdisk -l](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaVbV.png),
[Boot menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ex4Q8.png). Thank you in advance!  ps: I am sorry if i made a dumb mistake that i overlooked.

Comment: Form the snapshots I guess UEFI and GPT disks. If Secure Boot is still enabled you should check that way, either disabling it or double checking your GRUB setup took it into account.

Comment: i tried disabling the secure boot but it didnt help